golang fuse bazil issues with initiale directories
I use bazil go package https://pkg.go.dev/bazil.org/fuse
When I use mkdir, it's ok but I do not manage to set directories at startup
I want to define directories when the fs is mounted:
I thinks that I must get an fs node to add it in the FS but I dont understand how to do it because mkdir manage it.
$ ls -l mnt/
ls: impossible d'accéder à 'mnt/dir1': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce nom
ls: impossible d'accéder à 'mnt/dir2': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce nom
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? dir1
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? dir2

here the code :
$ go run main.go mnt

$ ls -l mnt/
ls: impossible d'accéder à 'mnt/dir1': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce nom
ls: impossible d'accéder à 'mnt/dir2': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce nom
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? dir1
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? dir2


There is my code :
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
    "syscall"

    "bazil.org/fuse"
    "bazil.org/fuse/fs"
)

var inodeCount uint64

type EntryGetter interface {
    GetDirentType() fuse.DirentType
}

type FS struct{}

func NewFS() FS {
    fmt.Println("FS")
    fs := FS{}
    return fs
}

func (f FS) Root() (fs.Node, error) {
    fmt.Println("Root")
    root := NewDir()

    root.Entries["dir1"] = NewDir()
    root.Entries["dir2"] = NewDir()
    return root, nil
}

type Dir struct {
    Type       fuse.DirentType
    Attributes fuse.Attr
    Entries    map[string]interface{}
    Name       string
}

func NewDir() *Dir {
    log.Println("NewDir")
    atomic.AddUint64(&inodeCount, 1)
    return &Dir{
        Type: fuse.DT_Dir,
        Attributes: fuse.Attr{
            Inode: inodeCount,
            Atime: time.Now(),
            Mtime: time.Now(),
            Ctime: time.Now(),
            Mode:  os.ModeDir | 0o777,
        },
        Entries: map[string]interface{}{},
    }
}

func (d *Dir) Mkdir(ctx context.Context, req *fuse.MkdirRequest) (fs.Node, error) {
    log.Println("Mkdir called with name: ", req.Name)
    dir := NewDir()
    d.Entries[req.Name] = dir
    return dir, nil
}

func (d *Dir) Attr(ctx context.Context, a *fuse.Attr) error {
    *a = d.Attributes
    log.Println("Dir Attr\n")
    log.Println("Attr permissions: ", a.Mode)
    log.Println("Attr: Modified At", a.Mtime.String())
    return nil
}

func (d *Dir) LookUp(ctx context.Context, name string) (fs.Node, error) {
    node, ok := d.Entries[name]
    fmt.Println("lookup: ", name)
    if ok {
        return node.(fs.Node), nil
    }
    return nil, syscall.ENOENT
}

func (d *Dir) GetDirentType() fuse.DirentType {
    fmt.Println("DirentType d")
    return d.Type
}

func (d *Dir) ReadDirAll(ctx context.Context) ([]fuse.Dirent, error) {
    log.Println("ReadDirAll")
    var entries []fuse.Dirent

    for k, v := range d.Entries {
        fmt.Println("name: ", k)
        var a fuse.Attr
        v.(fs.Node).Attr(ctx, &a)
        entries = append(entries, fuse.Dirent{
            Inode: a.Inode,         
            Type:  v.(EntryGetter).GetDirentType(),
            Name:  k,
        })
    }
    return entries, nil
}

func main() {
    //  flag.Usage = usage
    flag.Parse()
    var mountpoint string = "mnt"

    if flag.NArg() == 1 {
        mountpoint = flag.Arg(0)
    }
    fmt.Printf("starting fs on %s\n", mountpoint)
    c, err := fuse.Mount(mountpoint)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fs.Serve(c, NewFS())
    c.Close()
}


